# Is a non-null object from intent?.extras? nullable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bundle

Lets assume, there is a non-null enum `MainFlag` object ( like `enum class MainFlag { PARAM1, PARAM2 }`) in an Activity by `lateinit var`:

```
private lateinit var flag: MainFlag
```

Furtheron, I get that later in the `onCreate()` like:

```
flag = intent?.extras?.getSerializable(ARG_FLAG) as MainFlag
```

and I used to use this `flag` in that activity on several places with null-checks

```
flag?.let{
  //..
}
```

but then Android Studio complains:

> Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver of type
>   MainActivity.Companion.MainFlag

**I am not sure using it without null checks, because if `intent?.extras?` fails, flag will not be set, thus null?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it can be `null`. You are getting the warning because you are down casting to a not nullable type

```
intent?.extras?.getSerializable(ARG_FLAG) as MainFlag
```

should be

```
intent?.extras?.getSerializable(ARG_FLAG) as? MainFlag
```

Comment: Then I also have to modify `private lateinit var flag: MainFlag` to `private var flag : MainFlag? = null`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to declare the variable as

```
private lateinit var flag: MainFlag?
```

or

```
private var flag: MainFlag? = null
```

then you can set the value of `flag` like this

```
flag = intent?.extras?.getSerializable(ARG_FLAG) as? MainFlag
```

Now the flag variable is `nullable`. So you need to check for `nullable` everywhere in the code like this:

```
flag?.let{
  //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `intent?.extras?.getSerializable(ARG_FLAG)` will never be `null` (and also none of the intermediate objects: `intent` and `intent.extras`), then you can keep everything as is and just use `flag.let { ...` instead of `flag?.let { ...`.

If there is a chance that any of those is `null`, then you have to use a `MainFlag?`-type for your flag, e.g.:

```
private var flag : MainFlag? = null // having null in place basically makes the lateinit meaningless and rightfully lateinit does not allow nullable types

flag = intent?.extras?.getSerializable(ARG_FLAG) as? MainFlag
```

... or risk a `TypeCastException` when keeping `as MainFlag`.

The reason why Android Studio complains about the unnecessary safe call, is, that you specified the type as non-nullable `MainFlag` (indirectly via your `as MainFlag`-cast). So if you access `flag` it must already be there and it must be not-null (you said it so). The code however will fail at the cast, if there was a `null`-value involved, i.e. the cast to the non-nullable type could not succeed.

Comment: lateinit modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types

Comment: yeah, sorry... just copy/pasted... but the solution is relatively easy... just use `private var flag : MainFlag? = null` then...